# Does LibGDX only have tile based maps?

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine

I can only find tutorials on how to create tiled maps for LibgGDX, but I feel like a tiled map looks very boxy, and old-fashioned. I want a way to create a more cartoony, smooth look. Is there any other method of making maps in LibGDX, besides using the tile method? If not, is there another good game engine that I will be better of using instead?

Comment: You can do smooth transitions by hand if you want. For developping and indie game, tiledbased maps are really the best, as they are simple to make and handle.

Answer (score 0):

> a tiled map looks very boxy, and old-fashioned

That really depends upon the graphics, not the way of implementation.

The cartoony and smooth look can be achieved using tiled maps too. It mostly depends upon the assets.

Besides that, libGDX does not force you to use tiled maps. It is just one way to go at it. You can implement some raw stuff if you like, but I'd recommend using tiled maps for rapid prototyping as they are easy to create and manage.

Comment: Do you know what the non-tiled method would be called if I wanted to search it up? Thanks for your help

Comment: Well that'd really depend upon what you want to make. If the game design requires you to use tiles as level design is significant factor, and you don't like libgdx tiles, then you should try something other than libgdx. If design does not require strong focus on level design, then you should be good to go with implementing with just stage/actors. Good luck.

Comment: @TanmayPatil What do you mean with "libgdx tiles"? If you mean all those `Tiled...` features, you don't need to use them, even if you want to create Tile-Based maps with libgdx. You don't need to switch to another Engine/Framework, just because you don't like the `Tiled`support, you can easily manage the tiles yourself (like i did).

Comment: It's really about choice. What's the use of a framework if you don't have (or not going to use) the feature that you want the most? Reinventing the wheel (implementing tile management yourself) just to be able to stay in a framework in your comfort zone might not be the best idea (unless you need customization). Libgdx is really great and my personal favorite, but we should be pragmatic enough to keep our options open when we need something else. That is just my opinion anyways. YMMV. Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

Libgdx is a crossplattform framework, which helps you developing games.
This help includes also `Tile-based maps`, which they support with `TiledMapRenderer`, `TiledMapLoader`... But supporting something does not mean that you have to use it. It just means, that if you use it you will have it easier and you ll be faster.
I have to say that i never used `Tiled`, even if my `Map`s are all `Tile-based`. But you can easily create whatever kind of map you want (you can change every pixel individually if you want).
The difference is, that you have to manage everything yourself, wite your own `Mapeditor`, if you want to have one, manage the format of your Map files yourself, create your own `Maploader`...
Thats it.
Also think about this: Tile based games are easy to create and can look really good, if you use good graphics. Also you can change the size of the Tiles and so you can have more elements->more detail in your Map. So if you think it has to look "blocky" you probably don't know the power of tile maps.

Here you can see 3 different types of plattformer desings:
[2D Plattformer](http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2012/05/20/the-guide-to-implementing-2d-platformers/)

This should give you a bisc idea what other possibilities you have

Comment: wow thanks. That link has same well made maps. I guess you are right, I just didn't know the power of tiled maps!

Comment: Tiles have the advantage, that they are pretty easy to use. Also a level editor is easy to implement if you are using Tiles. But ofc they have some restrictions to.